# Retrieving current user inside Serializer Method in Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer for user profiles in Django Rest:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ......................
    ......................
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_status(self, obj):
        user =  self.context['request'].user
            if obj.user.userprofile in user.followed_userprofiles_set.all():
                return "following"
            else:
                return "notfollowing"
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (...., 'status',...)
```

And I have two views that use this serializer:

```
class Followers(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        #user who follow current user
        users = request.user.userprofile.followers.all()
        userprofiles= UserProfile.objects.filter(user__in=users)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(userprofiles, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and

```
class Friends(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        .................
        .................
        return queryset
```

One view is using APIView and other is using genericAPIView. When i request from genericAPIView, its working properly. But when i request from APIView, its giving me key error. How to retrieve the current user inside serializer method when APIView is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **you are manually instantiating the `UserProfileSerializer` in your `APIView` class without passing the `context`**, `KeyError` exception gets raised.

You should pass the `request` in `context` parameter when instantiating the `UserProfileSerializer` in your `APIView`.

```
class Followers(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        #user who follow current user
        users = request.user.userprofile.followers.all()
        userprofiles= UserProfile.objects.filter(user__in=users)
        context = {'request':request} # prepare serializer context
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(userprofiles, many=True, context=context) # pass context
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved the issue. I was not passing the context